# Raspberry pi 4 ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) missing packages

Tags: server, package-management, 20.04, raspberrypi

I have just installed ubuntu server 64 bit to my raspberry pi (with the official imager program), started to use it, but many packages can't be found. Like `ruby`, `python3-libotrrent`, etc and I get either `E: Unable to locate package libboost-python` or `E: Package 'python3-libtorrent' has no installation candidate`. Do you have any solution, I used raspbian previously, it worked but it was slower. Thanks for the replies!

## EDIT

My apt update output:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Fetched 312 kB in 2s (153 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Output for `sudo apt install ruby`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ruby is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ruby' has no installation candidate
```

## EDIT 2

Adding these lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

resulted in errors:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease                                                                                
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease                                                                              
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]                                       
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease                             
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages   
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [28.6 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages [1300 B]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages [139 kB]
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [46.8 kB]
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 c-n-f Metadata [3224 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages [932 B]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages          
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages            
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages        
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages  
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages    
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages        
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Err:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Err:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Fetched 479 kB in 4s (109 kB/s)      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt update` once ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention but yes

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1258480/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and the complete input and output showing packages that cannot be found.

Comment: @user535733 did it

Comment: Add [these lines](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/jngzgyYP9t/) to your ```/etc/apt/sources.list``` then run ```sudo apt update``` again.Those are the repositories that are being added when you check the entries (except **source code**) in **Software & Updates** in a graphical ubuntu.

Comment: It resulted in error:

Answer (score 0):

I've checked out these 2 guides. One for [Ubuntu](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/), the other for [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/ruby.md) (both Debian based so most packages are the same and can be installed from common sources).

Both seem to use `sudo apt install ruby-full`, rubby-full, NOT ruby.

If this doesn't work, u can consider using `sudo snap install ruby –classic` if you're ok with using snap.

Running apt list on my box:

```
apt list ruby
Listing... Done
ruby/bionic 1:2.5.1 amd64
```

In addition, you should update your question with your Ubuntu Server OS version.

Comment: The apt list results in:
`apt list ruby
Listing... Done

`
The snap worked, but the classic tag has the wrong character (not '--')

Comment: So you get the desired output when u run "ruby -v" right?

Comment: If this helped, please accept & upvote my answer!

Comment: Yes I get, however ruby was mostly just an example, that's why I mentioned 'many packages', because many deb packages cannot be found, as I mentioned e. g. python-libtorrent which don't have a snap version so this cannot be considered as a wilder solution

Comment: Installing packets from packet managers can't have a wider solution. Most of the time either the sources are wrong, or the packet we're trying to install itself. Provide me info like what's the output on trying to install python-libtorrent and your OS (update your question).